# jquery validate dinâmico

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="pages alert alert-success">
    <div class="questoes">
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd1"> 1</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd1"> 2</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd1"> 3</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd1">4 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="questoes">
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd2"> 1</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd2"> 2</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd2"> 3</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd2">4 </label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="pages alert alert-success"  >
    <div class="questoes">
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd3"> 1</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd3"> 2</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd3"> 3</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="rd3">4 </label>
    </div>
    <div class="questoes">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="rd4[]"> 1</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="rd4[]"> 2</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="rd4[]"> 3</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="rd4[]">4 </label>
    </div>
</div>


<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-proximo">Proximo</button>
```

//Javascript

```
    $("#btn-proximo").on("click",function(){
        var _arrInputs = [];
        $(".questoes").find(":input").each(function(){
            var thisName = $(this).attr("name");
            if (_arrInputs.indexOf(thisName) === -1) {
                _arrInputs.push(thisName);
            }
        });
        for(var i =0; i<_arrInputs.length;i++){
            alert(_arrInputs[i]);
        }
    });
```

Eu tenho um formulário em que cada vez que a pessoa apertar próximo deve-se verificar os campos que não estão preenchidos. Utilizo o plugin form validation.

Existe alguma forma dinâmica para verificar isso? eu armazenei dentro da array todos o `name` do radio, checkbox  etc.

- meu jsfiddle:
  https://jsfiddle.net/jaukku64/2/
- estou usando este plugin:
  http://formvalidation.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olhando a [API do plugin](http://formvalidation.io/api/), há algumas funções que podem ser utilizadas para validar campos ou grupos de campos individualmente.

Dentre eles, a que me chamou a atenção é a [`validateContainer`](http://formvalidation.io/api/#validate-container), pois a descrição diz que a função existe justamente para trabalhar com abas ou passo-a-passos do tipo *wizard*.

Entretanto, existe na documentação [algo específico sobre *wizards*](http://formvalidation.io/examples/#wizard) que diz que campos ocultos [não são validados por padrão](http://formvalidation.io/settings/#form-excluded), então provavelmente dá para fazer algo mais automático simplesmente chamando a validação no botão <kbd>Próximo</kbd>.

Além disso, ainda tem [um exemplo de como fazer um *wizard* usando Bootstrap](http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-wizard/). Veja o código:

### HTML

```
<!-- Include Bootstrap Wizard -->
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/1.2/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
#installationForm .tab-content {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
</style>

<form id="installationForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="active"><a href="#basic-tab" data-toggle="tab">Site information</a></li>
        <li><a href="#database-tab" data-toggle="tab">Database</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- First tab -->
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="basic-tab">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Site name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">URL</label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="url" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Owner email</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Description</label>
                <div class="col-xs-7">
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="description" rows="6"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Second tab -->
        <div class="tab-pane" id="database-tab">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Server IP</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dbServer" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Database name</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dbName" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Database user</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dbUser" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="col-xs-5">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="dbPassword" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Previous/Next buttons -->
        <ul class="pager wizard">
            <li class="previous"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Previous</a></li>
            <li class="next"><a href="javascript: void(0);">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="modal fade" id="completeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Complete</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p class="text-center">The installation is completed</p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Visit the website</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // You don't need to care about this function
    // It is for the specific demo
    function adjustIframeHeight() {
        var $body   = $('body'),
                $iframe = $body.data('iframe.fv');
        if ($iframe) {
            // Adjust the height of iframe
            $iframe.height($body.height());
        }
    }

    $('#installationForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            // This option will not ignore invisible fields which belong to inactive panels
            excluded: ':disabled',
            fields: {
                name: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The site name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                url: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The URL is required'
                        },
                        uri: {
                            message: 'The URL is not valid'
                        }
                    }
                },
                email: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The email address is required'
                        },
                        emailAddress: {
                            message: 'The email address is not valid'
                        }
                    }
                },
                dbServer: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The server IP is required'
                        },
                        ip: {
                            message: 'The server IP is not valid'
                        }
                    }
                },
                dbName: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The database name is required'
                        }
                    }
                },
                dbUser: {
                    validators: {
                        notEmpty: {
                            message: 'The database user is required'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        .bootstrapWizard({
            tabClass: 'nav nav-pills',
            onTabClick: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                return validateTab(index);
            },
            onNext: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                var numTabs    = $('#installationForm').find('.tab-pane').length,
                    isValidTab = validateTab(index - 1);
                if (!isValidTab) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (index === numTabs) {
                    // We are at the last tab

                    // Uncomment the following line to submit the form using the defaultSubmit() method
                    // $('#installationForm').formValidation('defaultSubmit');

                    // For testing purpose
                    $('#completeModal').modal();
                }

                return true;
            },
            onPrevious: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                return validateTab(index + 1);
            },
            onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                // Update the label of Next button when we are at the last tab
                var numTabs = $('#installationForm').find('.tab-pane').length;
                $('#installationForm')
                    .find('.next')
                        .removeClass('disabled')    // Enable the Next button
                        .find('a')
                        .html(index === numTabs - 1 ? 'Install' : 'Next');

                // You don't need to care about it
                // It is for the specific demo
                adjustIframeHeight();
            }
        });

    function validateTab(index) {
        var fv   = $('#installationForm').data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
            // The current tab
            $tab = $('#installationForm').find('.tab-pane').eq(index);

        // Validate the container
        fv.validateContainer($tab);

        var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($tab);
        if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
            // Do not jump to the target tab
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
</script>
```

---

Nota: nunca usei esta biblioteca, mas diga-se de passagem, ela parece muito boa e madura, com documentação bem completa. Difícil encontrar um projeto tão fácil de navegar assim.